# export datagridview to csv

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
    DataTable myTable = new DataTable("components");
    DataColumn mydatcolumn;

    mydatcolumn = new DataColumn();
    mydatcolumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    mydatcolumn.ColumnName = "Component";

    myTable.Columns.Add(mydatcolumn);

    mydatcolumn = new DataColumn();
    mydatcolumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    mydatcolumn.ColumnName = "Service Category";

    myTable.Columns.Add(mydatcolumn);

    mydatcolumn = new DataColumn();
    mydatcolumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    mydatcolumn.ColumnName = "Component Owner";

    myTable.Columns.Add(mydatcolumn);


    for (int i = 0; i < serviceList.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow mydatarow;
        //DataRow mydatarow2;
        mydatarow = myTable.NewRow();
        mydatarow["component"] = ComponentList[i];
        //mydatarow2 = myTable.NewRow();
        mydatarow["Service Category"] = sc[i];
        myTable.Rows.Add(mydatarow);
    }
    componentRGOdataGridView.DataSource = myTable;    

private void addCoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

As mention above, I am creating a DataTable with three columns and displaying the items in the 2 List<> (not shown above) on the datagridview using this dataTable. List populate rows for only 2 columns and the third column is for user input. On that button click event I want to write only those row in a file where user is giving input and ignore rest of the rows. How can I achieve this.
Many Thanks

Comment: What's actually your issue then? Getting the current row from the `OnClick` event? Attaching an event to the button? Or creating a CSV file from a given `DataRow`?

Comment: Getiing the rows for the datagridview and saving it in .csv file is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use componentRGOdataGridView.Rows to get all the [row](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.aspx) in the componentRGOdataGridView.
Then use [Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.cells.aspx) property from DataGridViewRow class to get the cell's value.
After this you can use your favourite csv writer to make a csv file.

You can try this code to print out cell's value to output window.

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in componentRGOdataGridView.Rows)
    {
        Debug.Write(item.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        Debug.Write(item.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine(item.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridView control provides the `DataGridView.GetClipboardContent()` method which formats the selected cells as a `DataObject` that can be placed into the Windows Clipboard. Then you can retrieve the contents of the Clipboard as a `TextDataFormat.CommaSeparatedValue`. This returns the contents of the Clipboard as a CSV formatted string, which can be written to a file. By using the DataGridView's provided methods `SelectAll()` you can select the entire DataGridView to copy into the Clipboard. You can even copy the header row too by specifying `DataGridView.ClipboardCopyMode` to be equal to the enum `DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText`.

Witness the simplicity of following code:

```
void SaveDataGridViewToCSV(string filename)
{
    // Save the current state of the clipboard so we can restore it after we are done
    IDataObject objectSave = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

    // Choose whether to write header. Use EnableWithoutHeaderText instead to omit header.
    dataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
    // Select all the cells
    dataGridView1.SelectAll();
    // Copy (set clipboard)
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent());
    // Paste (get the clipboard and serialize it to a file)
    File.WriteAllText(filename,Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.CommaSeparatedValue));

    // Restore the current state of the clipboard so the effect is seamless
    if(objectSave != null) // If we try to set the Clipboard to an object that is null, it will throw...
    {
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(objectSave);
    }
}
```

Note that I also took the precaution of saving the contents of the clipboard before I copied the DataGridView, so that I could restore it after I was done.

I believe this method is superior because you are using the framework already provided for you, and not re-inventing the wheel by looping through rows and cells, which is prone to errors.

Hope this solves your problems...